# Typescript interface with unknown number of generic properties which all should be typed as booleans

Tags: angular, typescript

I want to make a typescript interface with unknown number of generic properties which all should be typed as booleans. If I wanted to make an interface with property 'foo' and a generic value I would do:

```
export interface Foo<T> {
  foo: T;
}
```

Since I want to do basically the opposite I tried

```
export interface booleansMap<T> {
  T: boolean;
}
```

but I got

`'T' is defined but never used.(@typescript-eslint/no-unused-vars)`

from eslint

Having trouble finding this in the docs (probably not googling with the correct nomenclature) - so I was wondering if anyone understands and can explain how to make such an interface

It should be able to handle something like:

```
{
  foo: false,
  bar: true,
  baz: false
}
```

or

```
{
  foo: true,
}
```

or any other object with any number of properties as long as all of the values will be booleans...

Comment: It would be useful to show an example of what you think the generic type parameter `T` for `booleansMap` could be, and what type you would expect to get back.

Comment: @Psidom thats it - thanks! If you want to answer I'll except it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need generics for this. You can just use `[K: string]` to specify a general key:

```
type booleanMap = { [K: string]: boolean }
```

with interface definition:

```
interface booleansMap {
  [K: string]: boolean;
}
```

Or alternatively use `Record`:

```
type booleanMap = Record<string, boolean>
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBARg9nANhAhgOwLIrFAvFAbygG0BpALigGdgAnASzQHMBdS2BZdKAXwCg+oSBySo0AJQgBjPFElS4tACYAeGg2YAaEVzQA+AY2ARaAMxRTo8UeipYcBPlBIVqdRq0rXdAbj78gA)

Comment: Could you please add also an example with indexed interface? upvoted

Comment: Well in a way 'K' is a generic... it's just a generic for "key' I guess

Comment: @captain-yossarian Sure, just added

Comment: @HelloWorld Functionally yes, but not sure if I would call it generics since it's not a parameter that can be used to create new types.